# D3: scale and color for choropleth map

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, topojson, choropleth

I'm working on a D3 map as one of several prototypes for a project involving small areas statistics. I'm starting with a simple map and I am new to D3.

I have not been able to display a range of colors using either a threshold or quantile scale. I have written at least 6 examples to experiment with the many other examples that already exist but I simply cant get the range to display in the areas. I know I am close but there is something I am missing.

My example is on git at https://github.com/Monduiz/OL-explorer. I really would appreciate any insights to help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code I'm working with and the files are available at the link above.

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var colors = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range(colorbrewer.YlOrRd[7]);

var projection = d3.geo.azimuthalEqualArea()
    .rotate([100, -45])
    .center([5, 20])
    .scale(800)
    .translate([width/2, height/2])

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "OLMCSDfr.json")
    .defer(d3.csv, "data.csv")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, can, OLM) {
  var PopById = {};

OLM.forEach(function(d) { PopById[d.Id] = +d.OLMnb; });

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "SDR")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(can, can.objects.OLMCSDfr).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(PopById[d.Id]); });
  }
```

Comment: It's more helpful for us if you post a fiddle, rather than your live code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ready` function, you are referencing `d.Id` for each of the topojson features, which is currently undefined.

I switched your function passed to `fill` to grab `d.properties.SDRID` instead, which is in both the topojson features and your `OLM` list elements. The `forEach` statement must also be changed to match.

This seems to work:

```
function ready(error, can, OLM) {
  var PopById = {};

  OLM.forEach(function(d) { PopById[d.SDRID] = +d.OLMnb; });

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "SDR")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(can, can.objects.OLMCSDfr).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
        return colors(PopById[d.properties.SDRID]); });

}
```

Comment: Ben, this works. Thank you! When I saw your modifications, I had a "DOH" moment. The colors I get dont display well, black in the north and mostly red so I probably need to play with the scale.

Comment: Ok, when I use a threshold range, I get better results. Most of the areas have small numbers so it seems to work best with an arbitrary range. For the black areas, I probably need to define a zero class in the domain and range.

Comment: I don't know if adding another comment is useful but the black areas have nothing to do with the scale. I just realized that my data file is missing census subdivisions (CSD). The total CSDs is a little over 5000 and I have about 4000 in the data.csv. I just need to redo the table from my database to include all the areas and it will solve everything. So, the end result is a threshold scale using small classes like 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000 and making sure all areas are in the csv. Also, Ben, I would upvote you but I dont have enough reputation!